# sshfs "Connection reset by peer"

Tags: ubuntu, openssh, sshfs

```
ssh -i ~/keys/id_rsa root@192.168.1.201
Enter passphrase for key '/home/avin/keys/id_rsa': 
Last login: Tue Jul 17 11:01:28 2012 from 192.168.1.240
[root@rsh_management ~]# exit
logout
```

it's ok i'm in! but...

```
avin@avin-pc ~/ % sshfs -o ssh_command="ssh -i ~/keys/id_rsa" root@192.168.1.201:/ /mnt/201
root@192.168.1.201's password: 
root@192.168.1.201's password: 
root@192.168.1.201's password: 
read: **Connection reset by peer**
```

and this one too

```
avin@avin-pc ~ % sshfs -o IdentityFile=~/keys/id_rsa root@192.168.1.201:/ /mnt/201
Enter passphrase for key '/home/avin/keys/id_rsa': 
read: **Connection reset by peer**
```

Why do I get "Connection reset by peer"?

Comment: the problem was:
on server in file **/etc/sshd_config** 
this line was commented

> # Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

Comment: Post it as an answer below, @carcinogen75.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on server in file `/etc/sshd_config` this line was commented

```
# Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Comment: Just to clarify; this was on the server?

Answer (score 0):

If you get this from sshfs

```
read: Connection reset by peer
```

maybe help to set file to read only

```
chmod 400 /{{path_to_your_key}}/keypair.pem
```

and connect again.